# How to remove parameters from query builder?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with my query builder. I am using symfony. What i want to acomplish: I have a given query builder, and i want to count all rows based on this query. So i worked on following solution:

```
$aliases = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases();
$alias = array_values($aliases)[0];

$cloneQueryBuilder = clone $queryBuilder;
$from = $cloneQueryBuilder->getDQLPart('from');

$cloneQueryBuilder->resetDQLParts();

$newQueryBuilder = $cloneQueryBuilder
    ->select('count(' . $alias . '.id)')
    ->add('from', $from[0]);

$this->total = $newQueryBuilder->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

However im getting an exception : `Too many parameters: the query defines 0 parameters and you bound 1` Does anyone knows how to solve it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `setParameters` should overwrite all existing parameters.

Comment: Great it works! why i didnt think of that. so simple xD

Comment: Is this true? As far as I can tell, setParameters only updates the values of existing parameters or adds new ones. I cannot seem to find any method for removing a parameter from QueryBuilder once it's been added. See: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html#354

Comment: hm, the `ORM\QueryBuilder` updates and does not override. `DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder`overrides. Depends on what you're using. For reference: [ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html#337-364), [DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.3/source-class-Doctrine.DBAL.Query.QueryBuilder.html#_setParameters)

Answer (score 0):

As \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::$parameters is type of ArrayCollection, you can just call `clear` or `removeElement` on it.

```php
$builder->getParameters()->removeElement(
    $builder->getParameter('specificParameter')
);
```

```php
$builder->getParameters()->clear();
```

more about ArrayCollection - https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/1.6/index.html

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe the above answer is correct. As you can see, setParameters only updates the existing parameters. It does not remove any which are already set:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html#354

The solution I found was to iterate through the existing parameters and set each value to null.

```
foreach($queryBuilder->getParameters() as $key=>$value){
   $queryBuilder->setParameter($key,null);
}
```

Comment: Actually this does not work either. :( As far as I can tell this is simply not possible unless an additional method gets added.

Comment: I can see your point but how can you/we explain the fact that the exception that i was getting before has disappeared with @Joshua solution ?

Comment: Anyway i would like to know :P Obviously it shouldnt or maybe we are looking in a wrong place.